# sshuttle on Alpine Linux fails with "Unable to automatically find a supported method"

Tags: vpn, alpine-linux

I'm trying to use sshuttle on an Alpine VM. I was able to install the dependencies and compile the sources from GitHub. However, when I try to connect to my server, I get this error message:

`fw: fatal: Unable to automatically find a supported method. Check that the appropriate programs are in your PATH. We tried methods: ['nat', 'nft', 'pf', 'ipfw']`

`c: fatal: ['/usr/bin/sudo', '-p', '[local sudo] Password: ', '/usr/bin/env', 'PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sshuttle-1.0.6.dev12+gf928f94-py3.8.egg', '/usr/bin/python', '/usr/bin/sshuttle', '--method', 'auto', '--firewall'] expected READY, got b''`

What I don't understand is that the exact same thing works on my Ubuntu setup, where I don't have any of nat, nft, pf, or ipfw in my path. My two machines don't use the same version of sshuttle however: 0.78.5 on Ubuntu and 1.0.6.dev12+gf928f94 on Alpine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked throught the source code:

- ipfw method requires `ipfw` binary in $PATH
- nat requires `iptables`binary in $PATH
- nft requires `nft` binary in $PATH
- pf requires`pfctl` binary in $PATH

I suspect your Alpine lacks `iptables`, unlike Ubuntu which probably has them by default. Installing iptables should fix this.

I am no Alpine Linux user, but the package appears to be named iptables, so

```
apk add iptables
```

should do the trick.

Comment: It was that simple, thanks a lot!
By the way, when you say "Looked through the source code", do you mean sshuttle's source code?

Comment: @OpticAl yes, exactly. I checked files for different methods to see which binary they are actually calling: https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle/tree/7fc33c00201b483f75d3ca9817001fc095f23d2f/sshuttle/methods